# how do you reset this variable?

Tags: python

if you run the code on python and then input anything that isnt a number for "please enter the password length: " then put in a number after that then the code wont run properly. i think this is because the pl variable has already been assigned to the character that wasnt a number but im not sure how to reset a variable

```py
import random
def generator():
    yessir = 0
    pl = input("please enter the password length: ")
    if pl.isnumeric():
        pl=int(pl)
    elif pl==str(pl):
        print("thats not a number!")
        generator()
    if pl < 8:
        poga=input("That password is a bit short. Would you like to continue? YES or NO: ")
        if poga=="yes":
            yessir = 1
        elif poga == "no":
            generator()
        else:generator()
    yessir = 1
    if yessir == 1:
        password = (random.choice("!QAZ@WSX#EDC$RFV%TGB^YHN&UJM*IK<(OL>)P:?_{'"))
        while pl >= 1:
            hacker = random.randint(1,4)
            if hacker == 1: password = password+(random.choice("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
            elif hacker == 2: password = password+(random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
            elif hacker == 3: password = password+(random.choice("123456789"))
            elif hacker == 4: password = password+(random.choice("!@#$%^&*(){}|_+:<>?~`,./;'[]\-="))
            pl = pl - 1
    if pl <= 1:print (password)
generator()
```

Comment: The problem is you're looping by having the function call itself recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order in you function:

```
import random
def generator():
    yessir = 0
    pl = input("please enter the password length: ")
    if pl.isnumeric():
        pl=int(pl)
  
        if pl < 8:
            poga=input("That password is a bit short. Would you like to continue? YES or NO: ")
            if poga=="yes":
                yessir = 1
            elif poga == "no":
                generator()
            else:generator()
        yessir = 1
        if yessir == 1:
            password = (random.choice("!QAZ@WSX#EDC$RFV%TGB^YHN&UJM*IK<(OL>)P:?_{'"))
            while pl >= 1:
                hacker = random.randint(1,4)
                if hacker == 1: password = password+(random.choice("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))
                elif hacker == 2: password = password+(random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
                elif hacker == 3: password = password+(random.choice("123456789"))
                elif hacker == 4: password = password+(random.choice("!@#$%^&*(){}|_+:<>?~`,./;'[]\-="))
                pl = pl - 1
        if pl <= 1:print (password)
    elif pl==str(pl):
        print("thats not a number!")
        generator()
generator()
```